# Need to change the color of dress to black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Can anyone help change the color of pink latex dress to black without losing the shine and all
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You' seem to still be asking for tutorials-on-demand, which is not the purpose of this site. Please take the time to read the [Help pages](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Copy the layer make that layer black and white with a green filter. Run levels. mask the dress, then hue the hands abd fringes so you dont see secondary reflections of pink, And deal with your horrible jpg artefacts.

Comment: Same basic answer I gave to your [other question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144590/how-to-convert-any-fabric-to-look-like-leather-latex). Mask the dress, and use Adobe Camera Raw filter to reduce the noise, and convert to black and white - reducing reds and magentas in the B&W Mixer.

Comment: Alex and his latex obsession...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response. This website is perfect if anyone needs any photoshop help.

Comment: And lol @Joonas , seems like people are getting to know me now. haha :p

Comment: @alex you hould change your name to alex the latex

Comment: @Joonas that's really a good suggestion :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the selection of the part you want to change color of. I'll use pen too for that.

After that, apply *Gradient Map* adjustment layer to it. Add 4 or 5 color nodes and slide accordingly till you get desired result.

(You will still need to manually *fix* unwanted pink spots left behind after applying gradient map, for better finishing)

[image]

[image]

Gradient Map:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. It's perfect

Comment: Welcome. When are you posting your next latex question? 

Comment: lol will try to post asap :), looks like you also enjoying my latex questions

Comment: Nah I just checked your questions when Joonas commented.